# Cannot view mounts remotely

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have several Samba mounts on an Ubuntu server.  When I `ssh` into that box remotely (instead of working directly on the box), I cannot see the mounted file systems (ie, if I `ls` there are no results).

Is this normal, have my mounts failed to load in my absense, or is something else at play?

Answer (score 0):

How are your samba shares being mounted? Do you use `/etc/fstab` like:

```
//servername/sharename /mountdirectory smbfs username=windowsuserename,password=windowspassword 0 0
```

or do you mount them through file manager (nautilus or some similiar), and use Gnome Virtual File System (gvfs)?
If your mounts are permanents, through `fstab`, you should see them always, unless you have your `ssh` sessions, *chrooted* (in a safe sandbox). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrooted
To mount your samba share/resource manually you could use:

```
mount -t smbfs //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o  username=mywindowsusername,password=mywindowspassword
```

Can you post the output for the `mount` command on both scenarios, local session and ssh?